# jquery remove button can't delete row from database

Tags: jquery, button

I've a list with each li containing a remove button to remove it upon click and also the selected box data from my database. I've created an id biz_watch'.$biz_watch_id.' which is unique to each individual box. Using $.get call to the a server side php script to delete the table row.

But the script doesn't function. If i were to take away the get function, I'm able to remove the boxes but with the .get command, the boxes can no longer be removed. The following are the codes

```
    foreach($biz_watchlist as $biz_watchlist1){
         echo '<li class="biz_watch" id="biz_watch'.$biz_watch_id.'">';
         echo '<table style="width:100%">';
         echo '<td style="width:50%">';
         echo $biz_watch_details['5'];
         echo ' | <a class="remove_watch" id="remove_watch'.$biz_watch_id.'">remove</a>';
         echo '</td>';
         echo '<td>';
         echo '<span style="float:right">'.$biz_watch_details['19'].'</span>';
         echo '</td>';
         echo '</table>';
         echo '</li>';
    }

    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.remove_watch').click(function(){
            var li = $(this).closest('li.biz_watch');
            var action = '../delete_watchlist.php';
            var data = { id:13};
               $.post(action, data, function(){
                 li.fadeOut('slow', function() {
                     li.remove();
                 });
               });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

My Server side Script

```
      <?php
        $id = $_POST["id"];

        $query = "DELETE FROM dz0yn_biz_watchlist WHERE biz_id = $id";
        $delete_watch_row = mysql_query($query);
      ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure that this link is correct? '/.../delete_watchlist.php'
You might NOT need one of those dots... =)

Comment: Your id is probably `remove_watch'.$biz_watch_id`, but you want `$biz_watch_id` in your onlick handler only.

Comment: @benqus Yes. The link is correct. I substituted it with ... to shorten the url.

Comment: @smamatti You mean this command-->{id: $(this).closest('.biz_watch').attr('id')} will return remove_watch'.$biz_watch_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Prefixing a relative directory (..) with a / turns it into an absolute path that references itself. That's kinda pointless. the first / should be removed ('../delete_watchlist.php').
2. Break up your script. You're trying to combine too many things in one line which is confusing the issue.

This should accomplish what you're after, assuming your server side script succeeds.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.remove_watch').click(function(){
        var li = $(this).closest('li.biz_watch');
        var action = '../delete_watchlist.php';
        var data = { id: li.attr('id').substr(9) };
        $.post(action, data, function(){
            li.fadeOut('slow', function() {
                li.remove();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Note the comments on the question. He knows the path to the script is correct. He just shortened it for the sake of this question.

Comment: @Chris oh whao! Work like a charm. Thanks! Hmm. Just realised, boxes disappeared but query doesn't work.

Comment: boxes can be removed. Takes approx 5 seconds but the query doesn't load and the database rows still exists.

Comment: Have you tried calling your php page with a hard coded id to confirm that it is really working?

Comment: I tried substituting id: li.attr('id').substr(9) to id:13 as shown in my qn. Edited. But still the query don't work but my boxes are able to fadeout. I mean it doesn't make sense since shouldn't the boxes fade out upon success of my php script in this case?

Comment: @Josh Mein Solved! Apologize guys. Careless on my part. Copied Chris script but forget to replace the .../ in URL. Thanks Soo MUCH!

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) over [get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

```
$.post('/.../delete_watchlist.php', {id: $(this).closest('.biz_watch').attr('id')},function(){
    $(this).closest('.biz_watch').fadeOut("slow");
});
```

The [jquery4u blog](http://www.jquery4u.com/ajax/key-differences-post/) sums it up well:

> If the processing of a form is idempotent (i.e. it has no lasting observable effect on the state of the world), then the form method should be GET. Many database searches have no visible side-effects and make ideal applications of query forms.
>
> If the service associated with the processing of a form has side effects (for example, modification of a database or subscription to a service), the method should be POST.

**Edit**:

You are creating your table dynamically which means your .ready is called before the table is completely created; therefore, it will most likely not create the click function on all your rows.

You need to use the [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event to apply events to objects that will could possibly be created later.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.remove_watch').on("click", function(){
        $.get('/.../delete_watchlist.php', {id:  $(this).closest('.biz_watch').attr('id')},function(){
            $(this).closest('.biz_watch').fadeOut("slow");
        });
    });
});
```

**Edit**:

One final try :P. Since you only need the id of 12 not the whole biz_watch12, you can use replace to remove the biz_watch from your id to be sent to the server.

```
$(this).closest('.biz_watch').attr('id').replace("biz_watch", "");
```

Comment: Yes. I inserted an alert("success") under $(this).closest(.biz_watch').fadeOut("slow"); and it showed the alert box. But the box still doesn't fade out

Comment: Isn't $(this).closest(.biz_watch').fadeOut("slow"); the success handler in this case. What i mean is when the .post command succeed then this command--> $(this).closest(.biz_watch').fadeOut("slow"); will proceed?

Comment: No. Where can I catch that? I just don't see any errors in the error log of my firebug console.

Comment: Yes. It works fine and it shows Parameter
id biz_watch12
Source
id=biz_watch12.. or is it because my parameter id is wrong hmm..

Comment: I think i know now where the problem lies but have no idea how to go about it. No problems with the query. Problem lies where in the data sent over to the server side script. My parameter is bizwatch12 but what i really needed was 12. Any ideas how i can get just the number out?

Comment: I gotcha I will update my answer. Also, if you could help me clear out these unnecessary comments that would be nice.

Comment: Okay. Just changed my id so now it just sends id=12 to the server but the script still doesn't work

Comment: Which id did you change? The id of the html or did you do what I recommended? Numbers are not valid html ids and it could be the cause of another problem.